# Error using phpMyAdmin with Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, apache, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

We have an Amazon RDS instance and I want to manage it with phpMyAdmin.

I've got phpMyAdmin running, but there seems to be issues with the configuration I can't figure out.

My setup:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 7.0
- Apache 2.4
- phpMyAdmin 4.6.2

I did not install phpMyAdmin with `apt-get` because it was going to install PHP5 and MySql stuff. So I downloaded it from their site.

My `config.inc.php` below:

```
<?php

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

$i = 0;

$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'path.to.rds.amazon.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

I did not make other changes elsewhere. I did not create any phpmyadmin database. Because I read some blogs that the issue is with the database structure but I can't find the script that creates phpmyadmin defaults.

I'm getting the errors below when I login to phpMyAdmin:

```
The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
      Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.
```

clicking on *Find out why* would say this:

```
Configuration of pmadb… not OK
General relation features Disabled
```

and this other error

```
The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret).
```

and when I navigate in phpMyAdmin, it displays 403-forbidden, a phpmyadmin pop-up. Not the web server 403 page.

Can someone please point me to the right direction. I can't seem to find what's wrong with the **config.inc.php**.

Thanks!

Comment: Add this line $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '<any-password-you-like>'; in this file config.inc.php and then check

Comment: And for first error uncomment this line $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin'; in config.inc.php file